# A word for "engraving a pattern onto wood or metal using a redhot instrument"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this image in my head of someone engraving letters or patterns onto a piece of wood (flat or not) or on metal (but it doesn't have to be both, either wood or metal is fine) with an instrument that is made of metal (iron?) and it is red-hot, which is how the work is done. I am sure there must be a word and it is used in art, but not only.

My first guess was ***incise***, but it does not involve fire/heat:

> to cut the surface of something carefully with a sharp tool ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incise))

Is there a verb that describes the same action but using fire or a red-hot metal instrument? (I wonder what the name of that would be also, but my main question is the verb).

The result looks something like that

[image]

I need it for a metaphor:

> This experience was _______ in the depths of his being as with a red-hot iron (instrument - could it be ***chisel***?)

***Edit:*** I should have mentioned that the experience is not necessarily negative, though it may involve pain. In fact it is not. It has just been indelibly engraved in the soul.

Comment: Search the synonyms of 'engraving': *etch* and *carve* come to mind.

Comment: I did, but "etching" is rather done with some sort of acid, and "carving" doesn't seem to involve heat either.

Comment: Emblazon. . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you’re not really limiting the material that is being burned, the best word is probably [***pyrography***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrography), sometimes called *pokerwork*. When done on wood, the tool is usually called a *woodburner*, but might be a *poker*, a *branding iron*, or (improvised) a *soldering iron*.

Comment: For the metaphor, the experience might have been *branded* or *seared* into the depths of his being...

Answer (score 6):

The mark and the tool used to make the mark are both called a *brand*.

> **brand** noun
>
> ...
>
> 3 a (1) : a mark made by burning with a hot iron to attest manufacture or quality or to designate ownership
>
> ...
>
> 5 : a tool used to produce a brand

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brand

---

Today, we're so used to capitalism and so unused to branding irons, that it may seem like the above is the secondary meaning.  Perhaps it seems like first there was the concept of a brand as "a particular make of goods" and then we named the tool that made the brand label.  But the reverse is true.

The word *brand* seems to come from

> "Old English brand, brond "fire, flame, destruction by fire; firebrand, piece of burning wood, torch,"

https://www.etymonline.com/word/brand

Comment: Branding, however, is a different process from [pyrography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrography) or [pokerwork](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pokerwork) (pokerwork is normally a fairly crude form of pyrography). Pyrography and pokerwork are done using a heated point of some sort  whereas branding is the creation of a design or image using a hot iron featuring the entire design. The difference is analogous to  the difference between _drawing_ and _stamping_ or _printing_.

Comment: @In the OP’s sample sentence, though, *branded* fits well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *branded* (or *burnt*). It's not exactly what you were thinking of, but very close, and a verb that's used metaphorically in this sense. The instrument for branding would be an *iron* (for burning it could be a *poker*).

Answer (score 1):

#### Sear

1. > To char, scorch, or burn the surface of.

...

4. > **b**. To cause to be felt or remembered because of emotional intensity.

   > *The incident seared into the nation's memory.*

   [[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sear)]

The definitions given above are literal and figurative, respectively. The second one fits the bill nicely.

Thus you could write:

*This experience was **seared** in the depths of his being as with a red-hot iron.*

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Thank you for your efforts. By _second_ I mean the figurative meaning of _sear_ as in the example _The incident seared... _ Likewise, in the OP's example sentence.

Comment: @KannE Had to cudgel my brains a bit before the word popped up in my mind. I was thinking as I was writing the answer that someone would already have preempted this answer.

Comment: While a brand may sear, “sear” is not a word by itself that means “engrave a pattern onto wood”

Comment: @Jim Yes, it means [to burn the surface of something with sudden very strong heat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seared).  Also, I should have mentioned in the OP that the experience is not necessarily negative, though it may involve pain. In fact it is not.

Comment: @Jim Fair point! The word does however fit in the OP's example sentence— which has nothing to do with _engraving a pattern onto wood._ You could use the word and be sufficiently understood.